# Lombok + GWT : HandleAccessors failed

Tags: java, gwt, lombok

I'm getting too many compiling errors associated with Lombok and GWT.

The error is always the same:

[ERROR] Line 1: Lombok annotation handler class lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleAccessors failed - See error log.

I have tried two versions of Lombok:

1. Lombok 1.14.8
2. Lombok 1.12.6

Enviroment:

1.Eclipse Kepler started with Lombok agent in .ini  [

-javaagent:lombok-1.12.6.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok-1.12.6.jar

2. Compiling of gwt clases : GWT Pluggin with Lombok agent

-Xmx1024m -javaagent: .....\lombok-1.12.6.jar=ECJ -Xss1m -Dgwt.usearchives=false

I have tried the same with 1.14.8 but get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

GWT works directly on java sources, as explained in this link: https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html

Because this, you will need to use Delombok.

Answer (score 0):

How to managed to run the latest Eclipse + GWT plugin + GWT 2.8.2 + Lombok 1.8.2 together:

1. Add Lombok to eclipse (all standard steps)
2. Download special version of JDT used in GWT 2.8.2 (https://github.com/gwtproject/tools/raw/master/lib/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.2-CUSTOM-GWT-2.8-20160205.jar)
3. To make compile action working add to the advanced section the following arguments:

-javaagent:C:\Development\Lombok\gwt\lombok.jar=ECJ -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Development\Lombok\gwt\lombok.jar;C:\Development\Lombok\gwt\org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.2-CUSTOM-GWT-2.8-20160205.jar

4. To make the CodeServer (GWT Dev mode) add the same arguments to JVM argument (Arguments section) of the run configuration.